# pip Authentication to Gitlab Private PyPI Registry

Tags: python, pip, gitlab

I've got a PyPI Package hosted in Gitlab. I am able to succesfully download and install it by adding a `--index-url` parameter to the `pip install` command:

```
# This works
pip install MY-PACKAGE \
  --index-url https://__token__:<your_personal_token>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MY-PROJECT-ID/packages/pypi/simple
```

However, I want to not have to provide the index-url each time I install the package.

Ive tried adding a `~/.pypirc` with the contents:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    gitlab

[gitlab]
repository = https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MY-PROJECT-ID/packages/pypi
username = __token__
password = <GITLAB TOKEN>
```

as well as a `pip.conf` file in `~/.pip/pip.conf`, `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` with the contents:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://__token__:<GITLAB_TOKEN>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MY-PROJECT-ID/packages/pypi
```

With each of these, when I try to `pip install MY-PACKAGE` I get the error:

```
% pip3 install MY-PACKAGE

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://__token__:****@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MY-PROJECT-ID/packages/pypi
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MY-PACKAGE (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MY-PACKAGE
```

so my question is this -- How do you properly authenticate to the Gitlab PyPI Registry?

EDIT: Forgot to add I'm on MacOS, Python installed with asdf version manager, running virtualenvs

EDIT2: Figured it out. My URLs were missing `/simple` at the end:

```
# ~/.pypirc
repository = https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MY-PROJECT-ID/packages/pypi/simple

# ~/.pip/pip.conf
repository = https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MY-PROJECT-ID/packages/pypi/simple
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My URLs were missing `/simple` at the end:

```
# ~/.pypirc
repository = https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MY-PROJECT-ID/packages/pypi/simple

# ~/.pip/pip.conf
repository = https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/MY-PROJECT-ID/packages/pypi/simple
```